# How to trigger contrib module service function by route from my modules QueueWorker plugin processItem() function

Tags: queue

I'm working on a custom module that creates a queue for a contributed module "the streaming module" to be specific where my module is called streaming_transcode_queue. In my module I have a QueueWorker plugin to process the items in the queue that get added during hook_ENTITYT_TYPE_insert() when new streaming videos are uploaded, which works great and the items in the queue are exactly how I want them I've been using the queue_ui module to monitor things as I go.

Where I'm struggling is the actual process of the items in the queue when the queue worker runs the processItem() function. I can get the data for an item in queue with processItem, I'm just not sure how to get it to where I need it next.

Initially my hope was to get the Media ID ($mid) which is in the item data and then send it to the streaming modules service route (streaming.transcode) to transcode using the $mid because that service route uses the mid as a parameter.

For example if I know the $mid of a recently uploaded 'streaming video' and use that $mid in a url by manually pasting it in my web browser and visiting the streaming modules transcode service route at:

```
/admin/content/streaming/transcode-media/{mid}
```

The transcoding process will begin. Based on that I figured it would be easiest to trigger the url via the queue worker using some form of redirect.

Here is what I have and tried.

```
namespace Drupal\streaming_transcode_queue\Plugin\QueueWorker;

use Drupal\Core\Annotation\QueueWorker;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * Streaming Queue Worker.
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "streaming_queue",
 *   title = @Translation("Streaming Transcode Queue Worker"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 60}
 * )
 */
final class StreamingQueue extends QueueWorkerBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The database connection.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   */
  protected $database;

  /**
   * Main constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   Configuration array.
   * @param mixed $plugin_id
   *   The plugin id.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection $database
   *   The connection to the database.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, Connection $database) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->database = $database;
  }

  /**
   * Used to grab functionality from the container.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
   *   The container.
   * @param array $configuration
   *   Configuration array.
   * @param mixed $plugin_id
   *   The plugin id.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin definition.
   *
   * @return static
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('database'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Processes an item in the queue.
   *
   * @param mixed $data
   *   The queue item data.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public function processItem($data) {

    // Processing of queue items logic goes here.
    $mid = $data->mid;

//    $transcode = Url::fromRoute('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid])->toString();
//    $send_to = Url::fromRoute('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid]);
//    return Url::fromRoute('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid]);
//    return $this->setRedirectURL($transcode);

    return $this->transcodeItem($mid);
  }

  /**
   * Trigger transcoding via route for streaming.transcode service
   *
   * @param string $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   Response triggers transcoding.
   */
  public function transcodeItem(string $mid): RedirectResponse {

//    return $this->redirect('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid]);
    $url = Url::fromRoute('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid])->toString();
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
  }

}
```

Some lines in that are commented out as they were part of different attempts trying to get this to work.

I don't know if I need to include other 'use(s)' like including classes from the streaming module itself and use a different method to trigger the service provided by the streaming module.

For the most part I've been fumbling through things using various examples both on drupal.org and posted tutorials regarding creating and using a queue. Problem is most examples don't get real in depth in processing items using other services and functions (most are just db manipulation or creation of nodes) not sure if I really need db connection but I definitely don't need to create nodes or anything like that.

As it stands with the code for the queue worker above there are no errors and status message returned (when manually triggering the queue worker cron job) is: `Cron job Queue Worker: Streaming Transcode Queue Worker was successfully run.`

- The item in queue is removed but the route was not triggered so transcoding does not occur.

So, is this even possible the way I'm trying to do it? If not how should one go about doing this: "Use a queue worker to trigger a function provided by a service from another module?"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've already spent way to much time getting things this far and my head just hurts. If any other information is needed let me know, happy to provide.

Edit: (adding some more context)
So in reality the route I'm trying to trigger is not the actual service. Which may or may not help my situation..

The module I've built the queue for "streaming" has a sub-module called streaming_media_views, the submodule has the controller class I'm trying to trigger by route (from my modules plugin queue worker) is not a service. It "the controller" creates an array of parameters/setting and sends that to the "service" provided by the main module streaming.

Here is the routing.yml with the controller that accepts parameter {mid} like I'm trying to use.

```
streaming.transcode:
  path: '/admin/content/streaming/transcode-media/{mid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\streaming_media_views\Controller\ContentController::transcode'
    _title: 'Streaming transcoding video'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Administer media'

streaming.refresh:
  path: '/admin/content/streaming/transcode-media/refresh/{mid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\streaming_media_views\Controller\ContentController::refresh'
    _title: 'Streaming transcoding video'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Administer media'

streaming.clear:
  path: '/admin/content/streaming/transcode-media/clear/{mid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\streaming_media_views\Controller\ContentController::clear'
    _title: 'Streaming transcoding video'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Administer media'

streaming.delete:
  path: '/admin/content/streaming/transcode-media/delete/{mid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\streaming_media_views\Controller\ContentController::delete'
    _title: 'Streaming transcoding video'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Administer media'
```

This is the services.yml for streaming:

```
services:
  php_ffmpeg.factory:
    class: Drupal\streaming\Service\StreamingFactory
    arguments: [ '@php_ffmpeg.cache', '@logger.channel.php_ffmpeg', '@config.factory' ]
  streaming.representations:
    class: Drupal\streaming\Service\RepresentationService
    arguments: [ '@config.factory' ]

  cache.streaming:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
    factory: cache_factory:get
    arguments: [ streaming ]
    tags:
      - { name: cache.bin, default_backend: cache.backend.chainedfast }
  logger.channel.streaming:
    parent: logger.channel_base
    arguments: [ 'streaming' ]
  streaming.transcode:
    class: Drupal\streaming\Service\TranscodingService
    arguments: [ '@cache.streaming' , '@logger.channel.streaming' , '@config.factory' ]
```

Here is the Controller (ContentController.php)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\streaming_media_views\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * Manage video content.
 */
class ContentController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Transcode action.
   *
   * @param string $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Response data to template.
   */
  public function transcode(string $mid): array {

    $result = $this->exec($this->getParameters($mid));

    if ($result['status'] === TRUE) {
      $extra = [
        'mid' => $mid,
        'playlist' => $result['playlist']['url']['playlist_real_url'],
        'poster' => $this->preparePoster($result),
      ];

      // Setting poster to video preview.
      // I try to set the poster of `Media: streaming_video`,
      // otherwise I try to use the first generated thumbnails,
      // or as a last option I put FALSE and the player will use
      // the first frame of the video as poster.
      // Read from the bottom up.
      $result['media-poster-preview'] =
        // First thumbnail generated.
        $this->getMediaPoster($mid)['url'] === FALSE && isset($extra['poster'])
        ? \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')
          ->getViaUri(array_key_first($extra['poster']))->getExternalUrl()
        // Otherwise, media->field_poster['url'] or FALSE.
        : $this->getMediaPoster($mid)['url'];

      $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\streaming_media_views\Form\TranscodeForm', $extra);
    }
    else {
      $form = FALSE;
    }

    return [
      '#theme' => 'streaming-media-views-transcode',
      '#result' => $result,
      '#form' => $form,
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Refresh video streaming.
   *
   * @param string $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   Response data to template.
   */
  public function refresh(string $mid): RedirectResponse {
    $videoParameters = $this->getParameters($mid);
    $videoParameters['refresh-if-exists'] = TRUE;

    $this->exec($videoParameters);

    return $this->redirect('streaming.transcode', ['mid' => $mid]);
  }

  /**
   * Clear video streaming data.
   *
   * @param string $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   Response data to template.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  public function clear(string $mid): RedirectResponse {
    $videoParameters = $this->getParameters($mid);
    $videoParameters['refresh-if-exists'] = TRUE;

    $result = $this->exec($videoParameters, TRUE);

    if ($result['status']) {
      $mediaObject = Media::load($mid);
      $mediaObject->set('field_playlist', '');
      $mediaObject->set('field_poster', '');
      $mediaObject->save();
    }

    return $this->redirect('view.media.media_page_list');
  }

  /**
   * Delete media and video streaming data.
   *
   * @param string $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   Response data to template.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  public function delete(string $mid): RedirectResponse {
    $videoParameters = $this->getParameters($mid);
    $videoParameters['refresh-if-exists'] = TRUE;

    $result = $this->exec($videoParameters, TRUE);

    if ($result['status']) {
      $mediaObject = Media::load($mid);
      $mediaObject->delete();
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Media id: @id deleted.', ['@id' => $mid]));
    }
    return $this->redirect('view.media.media_page_list');
  }

  /**
   * This method call "streaming.transcode" service.
   *
   * @param array $videoParameters
   *   Video parameters array.
   * @param bool $clear
   *   If clear video transcode data.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Result of video transcoding.
   */
  private function exec(array $videoParameters, bool $clear = FALSE): array {
    $result = $clear
      ? \Drupal::service('streaming.transcode')->delete($videoParameters)
      : \Drupal::service('streaming.transcode')->video($videoParameters);

    if ($result['status'] === TRUE) {
      if (isset($result['message']) && !empty($result['message'])) {
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($result['message']);
      }
    }
    else {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addError($result['message']);
    }

    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * Get video parameters from Media.
   *
   * @param int $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Video data configuration.
   */
  private function getParameters(int $mid): array {
    $mediaObject = Media::load($mid);
    $file = File::load($mediaObject->field_media_video_file->target_id);

    return [
      'video-data' => [
        'uri'  => \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri()),
        'name' => $file->getFilename(),
        'id'   => $file->id(),
        'uuid' => $file->uuid(),
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Prepare poster radio options.
   *
   * @param array $result
   *   Data width jpg and gif array.
   *
   * @return array|null
   *   If there are data, it returns the processed data.
   */
  private function preparePoster(array $result): ?array {
    $poster = [];

    foreach ($result['thumbnails']['jpg'] as $key => $item) {
      $poster[$item['relative_path']] = '<img src="' . $item['url'] . '" width="200" height="200" />';
    }
    foreach ($result['thumbnails']['gif'] as $key => $item) {
      $poster[$item['relative_path']] = '<img src="' . $item['url'] . '" width="200" height="200" />';
    }

    return count($poster) > 0 ? $poster : NULL;
  }

  /**
   * Return media poster if it is set.
   *
   * @param int $mid
   *   Media id.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Result array [ 'url' => string , 'uri' => string ]
   */
  private function getMediaPoster(int $mid): array {
    $mediaObject = Media::load($mid);
    $file = $mediaObject->field_poster->target_id
      ? File::load($mediaObject->field_poster->target_id)
      : FALSE;

    if ($file) {
      return [
        'url' => \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')
          ->getViaUri($file->getFileUri())->getExternalUrl(),
        'uri' => $file->getFileUri(),
      ];
    }
    else {
      return ['url' => FALSE, 'uri' => FALSE];
    }

  }

}
```

I'd post the service class as well but that would exceed this posts character limits.

Maybe that will shed some light on this to the right person!

I hate to assume but I'm guessing using a redirect in a queue worker isn't going to do anything. At least it doesn't appear to (I know the URL is correct that I'm trying to redirect to as I logged it just to be sure) it just doesn't do anything.

So how can I use that controller in my plugin? In all honesty other than extending base Drupal classes for forms, settings and things in my own plugin classes which generally has enough documentation to get the job done. I have no idea nor do I fully understand (yet) how to work with classes by extending say a contributed modules class to use it's functions in my class. Which leads me back to my assumption guessing instead of a redirect some how I have to include the controller or extend the controller in my own plugin or service class, I just don't know how. I've read a lot on container dependency injection but again if that's possible how for this situation? Or is my logic just deeply flawed and I'm going about it all wrong!

Comment: Does the contrib module provide an API for the transcoding service to use it programmatically? If not, create an issue or debug what is happening after submitting the transcoding action in the module's form.

Comment: No direct API for the streaming module. I've debugged what is happening when transcode via the modules form. The form has operations attached to the media type and the operation to transcode sends to the $mid to the route I'm trying to use - as listed above. In manual queue actions (a form interface I setup up doing similar works as expected) I'm just not sure how to do the same via the QueueWorker as there is no form for user interaction being it should only be triggered on cron.